# Did John Locke have a mental condition?

Tags: character, lost

In Lost series, John Locke becomes obsessed with his father who betrayed him. John drives to his house every day and just observes his father. It gets to the point that John trades his beloved for this matter.

Did John have some kind of mental condition?

Comment: Obsessing over a topic does not mean someone has a mental condition...

Comment: Many conditions originate from some sort of obsession. Here, I am looking for one that matches John Locke. If there is one of course.

Comment: Locke had a lot of social issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### He had anger issues and depression at different points in his life.

The episode *Orientation*, shows that he joined an anger management group therapy class in 1995.

[image]

The episode *The Man from Tallahassee* shows that Locke later suffered from depression.

> LOCKE: You think I'm temporarily disabled?
>
> GOVERNMENT WORKER: Depression can be temporary, yes. And since you see fit to stop going to therapy, I guess you're all better.
>
> LOCKE: [stands up] Guess I am.

While it's possible he had some form of OCD or something similar, there's no way to know for sure.